# Python-It does not let me write to a text file

Tags: python

```
   myfile.write(Car_Number_plate+str' went at',+ Speed_In_Miles_Per_Hour+'/n')
```

I am getting an syntax error on python, I am trying to write to a text file.

Comment: Does it work if you do each part as a separate write?

Comment: remove the comma and str'. your syntax is just pain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would. Here is valid syntax for what you are trying:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as myfile: 
    myfile.write(Car_Number_plate + ' went at ' + Speed_In_Miles_Per_Hour + '/n')
```

To make it better, you probably meant to type `\n` for a line break, not `/n` and you probably want to make sure those variables are strings or don't use `+` to combine them. You should also make it more PEP8 friendly. So:

```
car_number_plate = "ABC123"
speed_in_miles_per_hour = 33

with open("file.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write("{0} went at {1} mph \n".format(car_number_plate, speed_in_miles_per_hour))
```

Comment: this is  an error i m getting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PShah\Documents\School\GCSE\TASK2a.py", line 38, in <module>
    myfile.write(Car_Number_plate + ' went at ' + Speed_In_Miles_Per_Hour + '/n')
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
>>>

Comment: Yup, because it wasn't converted to string and you used `+` on it, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much you even made it so it comes on separate lines in the text file thanks a lot.